# Laravel 10 - UnexpectedValueException - Invalid route action, how to setup route namespace in route namespace

Tags: php, laravel, nested-routes

I have upgraded my Laravel application to version 10 and encountered an issue with setting up a route with a namespace. In previous versions of Laravel, I used the following code in my routes/web.php file to set up a route with a namespace:

[image]

But in Laravel 10, this doesn't seem to work anymore. I get an "Invalid route action" error with the namespace included in the action parameter.

[image]

I've managed to fix my first route on the picture with this code, and now this route works well:

```
Route::namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Main')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', IndexController::class)->name('main.index');
});
Route::namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Admin')->prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Main')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Main\IndexController::class)->name('main.index');
    });
});

   Auth::routes();
```

But I don't know how to fix second route with namespace in namespace.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to properly set up a route with a namespace in Laravel 10? Thank you in advance!

P.S I'm using __invoke() method in my controllers

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Main;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        return view('main.index');
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a `Admin` directory in your image.

Comment: From what Laravel version did you upgrade?

Comment: one sec, I'll change the image

Comment: @Volex Please add any relevant code as text.

Comment: I think the namespaces are additive. The first one should be `'App\Http\Controllers\Admin'` and the second should be `'Main'`

Comment: @bassxzero yes, you're right. now it works 

`Route::namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Admin')->prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::namespace('Main')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Main\IndexController::class)->name('main.index');
    });
});`

Comment: it seems that i've tried same code before but it haven't worked, but now it works. )

Comment: Remove the `namespace` method, you are literally importing the class (`use xxx\yyy\zzz;`) so no need for namespaces, literally use `YourController::class`...

Comment: @matiaslauriti then you need to use aliases in `use xxx\yyy\zzz`, right?

Comment: @Volex no, only when the imported class is not unique in name

Comment: @matiaslauriti In my post, I described that I use the `__invoke` method, so my controllers for different resources will have the same names, in accordance with the best practices of assigning names, such as Index, Show, Store, Update Controller, and so on. Therefore, aliases cannot be avoided when importing controllers.

Answer (score 1):

I think the namespaces are additive. The first one should be `'App\Http\Controllers\Admin'` and the second should be `'Main'`

E.G

```
Route::namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Admin')->prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::namespace('Main')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Main\IndexController::class)->name('main.index');
    });
});
```

Comment: btw, if to put a folder with name admin to /public folder, then this the route /admin will not work. I found this because I've added this folder to put there assets for admin panel)